# date of birth session array displayed as "array" not day/month/year

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to get the users Date of Birth to display on the page from the session but it displays the word `Array` instead.. I checked the database and I know the data of birth has been saved properly its just it wont display it in the view and I think that's probably due to the debugger saving the date of birth as

`'dob' => array(
            'day' => '25',
            'month' => '04',
            'year' => '1992'
        ),`

I'm calling the date of birth in the view using

```
<td><?php echo __('Date Of Birth'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo h($this->Session->read('Auth.User.dob')); ?></td>
```

and this works for all the other users information e.g name, surname etc.

Why does it show array instead of dob, and how can I change it to show the date of birth I inputted instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dob = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.dob'); 
echo $dob['day'] . '/' . $dob['month'] . '/' . $dob['year'];
```

But this isn't exactly usable. Why are you storing it in this format in the first place? Post the code that saves the `dob`. If `dob` is a `date` Cake *should* store it as `YYYY-MM-DD` for you, so it would seem something is not right.

Answer (score 2):

That's PHP 101, if you try to echo an array it will output "Array". CakePHP will not magically convert the array to string for you. Echo the day, month, year separately or first create a string concatenating each date part and echo that.